# Objective-c Coreplot graph scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe, core-plot

I generated a scatterplot graph.My requirement is to swipe the graph part by part ie,if 10 columns of plot r shown on the screen,on the swipe the next 10 columns need to be shown.

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
 NSLog(@"point.x=%lf,point.y=%lf",point.x,point.y);
 return YES;
}
```

This gives the point dragged..how can i achieve my requirement with this method or is their any other way to figure it out?

Anybody please help...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a swipe gesture recognizer to the hosting view. When you get a gesture, change the plot space range to show the next set of data. You can animate the change to the plot range with `CPTAnimation`.